# How to assign variables in R?

Tags: regex, r, variables

I have:

```
for ( i in 1 :10){
    d= read.delim(paste("try",i,".txt",sep=""),head=T)
    assign(paste("try",i,sep=""),d)
}
```

then I have try1-try10

later in my code I want to use try1-10:

```
if( j ==1){ myVar=try$j}
```

So my Question is: how can I assign `myVar` to `try$j` ??  (`paste("try",j,sep="")` does not work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See related question and answer, here: [Dealing with repetitive tasks in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972634/dealing-with-repetitive-tasks-in-r/5972669#5972669)

Basically, instead of having multiple data frames in your workspace, combine them into a list of data frames. Then you can use loops, lapply, etc without having to jump through syntactic hoops.

Answer (score 2):

What you really want is:

```
try = list()
for ( i in 1 :10){
    d= read.delim(paste("try",i,".txt",sep=""),head=T)
    try[[i]] = d
}
```

Then

```
if(j==1){ myVar=try[[j]]}
```

or, since j==1 anyway:

```
if(j==1){ myVar=try[[1]]}
```

simples!