# self-assigning objects after applying the same function to each object

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to sometimes apply the same function to multiple objects present in the environment and assign those objects to themselves. But this often requires writing down multiple self-assignment operators, which is not efficient and error-prone.

Here is a minimal version of this routine:

```r
# setup
library(magrittr)
library(tibble)

# creating a few dataframes for a demo
df1 <- mtcars
df2 <- ToothGrowth
df3 <- anscombe

# performing the *same* operation on 3 different objects
# and self-assigning using magrittr's assignment pipe
df1 %<>% as_tibble(.)
df2 %<>% as_tibble(.)
df3 %<>% as_tibble(.)
```

Instead of repeating `as_tibble` three times here, is there a way for me to self-assign objects by specifying the function I want to apply to all of them *only once* (see `zeallot::%<-%` for inspiration).

I'd prefer if the solution is from the `tidyverse` packages, but also don't mind a `base-R` solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972634/dealing-with-repetitive-tasks-in-r/5972669#5972669

Comment: Thanks. In `tidyverse`, do I just replace `lapply` with `purrr::map`?

Comment: That said, my question is a bit different though, as I'd like the objects to be self-assigned after modification. The solution you pointed out stores the modified objects in a list, which means I would then need to keep track of which object belongs at which position in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `zeallot`

```
library(zeallot)
library(purrr)
map(mget(ls(pattern = '^df\\d+$')), as_tibble) %->%
          c(df1, df2, df3)
```

-checking

```
 head(df1)
# A tibble: 6 x 11
    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  21       6   160   110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
2  21       6   160   110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
3  22.8     4   108    93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
4  21.4     6   258   110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
5  18.7     8   360   175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
6  18.1     6   225   105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
head(df2)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
    len supp   dose
  <dbl> <fct> <dbl>
1   4.2 VC      0.5
2  11.5 VC      0.5
3   7.3 VC      0.5
4   5.8 VC      0.5
5   6.4 VC      0.5
6  10   VC      0.5
head(df3)
# A tibble: 6 x 8
     x1    x2    x3    x4    y1    y2    y3    y4
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    10    10    10     8  8.04  9.14  7.46  6.58
2     8     8     8     8  6.95  8.14  6.77  5.76
3    13    13    13     8  7.58  8.74 12.7   7.71
4     9     9     9     8  8.81  8.77  7.11  8.84
5    11    11    11     8  8.33  9.26  7.81  8.47
6    14    14    14     8  9.96  8.1   8.84  7.04
```

Answer (score 2):

Start by putting objects in a named list. You can then use `map`/`lapply` to iterate over each and apply the function that you want.

```
library(tidyverse)

list_df <- lst(df1, df2, df3)
result <- map(list_df, function(x) {
              as_tibble(x)
              #do more things
            })
```

If you want to transfer this changed data to the original objects use `list2env`.

```
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)
```